# How to split the rows using awk?

Tags: awk

I have a text file as follows.

```
 A/B     C/D     E/F 
  1      0.6     4.6  
 2.3      2      0.78 

 A/B     C/D     E/F
  2      5        2
  3      6        4
  ...
  ...
  ...
  ...

 A/B     C/D     E/F
 5       0.8     0.88
8.88     0.35    0.68
```

I have to change the rows in the following way. How can I do this with awk? How to save the output to a spreadsheet?

```
A     B    C     D    E     F 
1   2.3   0.6    2   4.6   0.78
2    3    5      6    2    4 
...
...
...

5   8.8   0.8   0.35  0.88  0.68
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with `kev`. Change the record separator from newline (default) to nothing:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS=""; OFS=FS="\t"; print "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" } { split ($2, one, " "); split ($3, two, " "); print one[1], two[1], one[2], two[2], one[3], two[3] }' file.txt
```

Results:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F
1   2.3 0.6 2   4.6 0.78
2   3   5   6   2   4
```

**EDIT:**

I think you may need to delete leading and/or lagging whitespace first (I would use `sed` for this) and then pipe output into the above `awk`:

```
sed 's/^[ \t]*//; s/[ \t]*$//' file.txt | awk 'BEGIN { RS=""; OFS=FS="\t"; print "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" } { split ($2, one, " "); split ($3, two, " "); print one[1], two[1], one[2], two[2], one[3], two[3] }'
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you for your answer. your code is only working for first two rows. I have lot of rows in my text file(please see my edited question). How can I change your code?

Comment: The above should work for multiple rows/records. See my changes to remove possible whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

#### `awk`:

```
awk '
BEGIN{
    RS=""
    print "A", "B"
}
{
    print $4, $7
}' input.txt
```

#### reuslt:

```
A B
1 2.3
2 3
```

---

When `RS` is `empty`, awk will interpret the data as multiple-line records.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have lot of rows in my text file. Please see my edited question.

Comment: If your records are separated by empty line, this command will work.